# Converting my submit button to a link and keeping the same style

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, submit

I have form submit buttons that are styled with some css. At the moment I used only submit buttons on the site but for some pages it is better to just use a link. 
Now I'm trying to change that, but I'm not quitting getting the exact result that I'd like to have.
They keep expanding (width:100%;) untill they reach the container, but the link gets out of the container and I dont know why.

Why is the link, not growing untill it reaches the container like the button? I'd prefer to keep using the same class for both the button as the link, but if that isn't possible I'll use different owns.

I've made a quick fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/QPRFK/

Assume the divs are my container

```
<div>
    <input type="submit" value="submitBtn" class="btn">
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" class="btn">link</a>
</div>
```

The css

```
.btn {
  background-color:#EE3399;
  border:3px solid #A10055;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#26328c;
  font-family:Verdana;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  padding:6px 24px;
  text-decoration:none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  text-align:center;
}

div{
    width:750px;
    background:green;
    margin-bottom:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from the fact that `width: 100%;` is just based just on content, not padding or borders. Since you have both, the padding and borders extend too far.

CSS3 `box-sizing: border-box;` will fix your problem. It is wise to use vender-specifc tags...

http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
box-sizing: border-box;         /* Opera/IE 8+ */
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quick, easy fix try adding `box-sizing: border-box;` to your css for the anchor tags.

Most elements have some default styles applied to them either by the specifications or the browser. The `input[type="submit"]` element is given this by default, whereas `<a>` is not.

Comment: This did the trick, why is that?? I'll accept answer in 10 minutes